# What should you do when you have a good answer to a closed question?

Tags: discussion

I wanted to find out how to delete folders that are older than X days. Then, I found this question:

*https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32992498/how-to-delete-folders-older-than-two-days/*

The title of the question is perfect; however, the question itself is poorly written and got closed.

There was no good answer that solved the problem. I also could not find a similar question on Stack Overflow (only how to delete files that are older than X days, but this is very different!).

I now figured out how to do it and produced a code snippet, and I would like to share it. But since the question is closed, I can't do it.

What should I do now if I want to share my answer? I was actually thinking of asking a new question on Stack Overflow only to provide my answer. But I wasn't sure if this is really a good thing to do.

Comment: Are you cruising for old, [closed](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/345240/why-is-the-question-how-can-i-create-variable-names-within-a-loop-not-constru) questions to answer? If the question is closed, you can't answer it. That's the point for that state. Asking a duplicate question for a closed one doesn't seem a great idea to me.

Comment: Fix the question and then wait until it may get reopened. You can't do anything else with that question.

Comment: Add your answer to this question: [How to remove files/folders older than a certain time](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7573967/how-to-remove-files-folders-older-than-a-certain-time) or [How to delete files from directory based on creation date in php?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2205738/how-to-delete-files-from-directory-based-on-creation-date-in-php)

Comment: @yivi: It won't be a duplicate question, though. It will be on the same topic but if the original was so atrocious as to be unsalvageable, might as well just start again. In theory we could edit the original and wait for it to be re-opened as Tom suggests, but in practice making such substantial edits is frowned upon and re-opening is unlikely.

Comment: The question may be closed for a reason other than being poorly written: opinion-based, too broad, etc. In such cases, write a blog post.

Comment: @yivi why would you think that I searched explicitly for old, closed questions to answer? I even explained in my question in detail how I came to my question. Nothing to add here.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

If no duplicate exists on the whole site, rewrite the question properly and self-answer it.

It's more likely that there is already a good place for your answer, though. Some suggestions have been made in the comments above.

Comment: Additionaly: Post a comment with a reference to the duplicate question

Comment: You can't answer a question if it's closed... if you mean create a new question (which isn't a probllem) then you need to make that more specific. I'd clean the existing question up and try to reopen it.

Comment: @Ben: Yes, that's what rewrite means. Five other people got it. As for cleaning the existing question and trying to reopen it, that was covered in comments: it won't work.